# How can a family of spherical neighborhood to be a topology of a metric space?

Tags: general-topology

I am learning topology. And my textbook states that for a metric space $X$,$\{U|U = \cup_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}(x,\epsilon_{x})\}$ can be a topology of that. My question is that if $X = \{a_1,a_2\}$, how can $\{U|U = \cup_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}(x,\epsilon_{x})\}$ be its topology?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? You just test if a given family of subsets satisfies the definition of topology.

Comment: @freakish Given set $X = \{p\}$ there is no spherical neighborhood $B$ to be equal to the $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by "spherical neighbourhood"? Usually $B(x,e)=\{y\in X\ |\ d(x,y)<e\}$ is an open ball. In the case when $X$ has only one point then **every** neighbourhood of that point is entire $X$. If $X=\{a_1,a_2\}$ then $B(a_1, d(a_1,a_2)+1)=X$. Apply those definitions and then you will see how it works.

Comment: @freakish Thanks a lot, it seems that I misunderstand the definition. Now I understand!

Answer (score 1):

Just think about the $\epsilon$-ball $B(a_1,\epsilon)$ centered at $a_1$.

Since $X=\{a_1,a_2\}$ is a metric space, denote the distance between $a_1$ and $a_2$ by $d(a_1,a_2)>0$.

1. If $0<\epsilon\leq d(a_1,a_2)$, then $B(a_1,\epsilon)=\{x\in X\mid d(a_1,x)<\epsilon\}=\{a_1\}$.
2. If $\epsilon>d(a_1,a_2)$, then $B(a_1,\epsilon)=\{x\in X\mid d(a_1,x)<\epsilon\}=\{a_1,a_2\}=X$.

Similarly, we have $B(a_2,\epsilon)=\{a_2\}$ or $X$ according to $\epsilon$.

Therefore, the topology on $X$ is nothing but the discrete topology, $\{\varnothing, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, X\}$.

Comment: If OP wanted the topology on $X$ consisting of $\epsilon$-balls centered at only one fixed point, say $a_1$ (as @freakish pointed out), then the topology is nothing but the Sierpinski space $\{\varnothing, \{a_1\}, X\}$.